# Массив, в котором по 2 раза повторяются разные числа

Tags: массивы, c++

Как создать массив, в котором по 2 раза повторяются разные числа:

```
mas[12] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, ... };
```

Только в случайном порядке:

```
mas[12] = { 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, ... };
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте функцию [random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/).

```
std::random_shuffle(mas, mas + 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно Стандарту `C++14` функции `std::random_shuffle` признаны устаревшими (D.12):

> The function templates `random_shuffle` are deprecated.

Вместо неё следует использовать [`std::shuffle`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.random.shuffle). Пример кода взят [отсюда](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Можно еще отметить, что в C++17 планируется удаление `std::random_shuffle` и других устаревших функций, так что код с ними просто перестанет компилироваться в будущем.

Comment: @Flowneee я думал, это очевидно, что не стоит использовать функции, помеченные устаревшими :) Рано или поздно их удаляют из Стандарта. Хотя поддержка, как мне кажется, будет оставлена. Надо ведь как-то старый код собирать без модификаций.